# Binding Redirect a namespace to a satellite assembly

Tags: .net, resources

I have an application that points to some resource files.  I don't want to modify that application but I need to update the resource file.  However, the resources are compiled as part of that application.  The potentially good news is that they are in a separate namespace within the application.

What I did is copy the resources into a separate assembly and named the namespace exactly the same, and incremented the version to be 2.0.0.0.  Is it possible to use the web.config to do a bindingRedirect to use the newer resource assembly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to do.  You can create an satellite assembly that matches all the same Assembly metadata information (namespace included) and then overwrite the existing "culture-specific" DLL in the existing compiled application folder.